# Django entries archiving

Tags: python, django

I have quite a big table (about 4M of entries) for emails that are sent by Django application. The more it grows the slower the queries are. I came up with the idea to archieve entries that are older than 3 months.

Could anyone give any advice on implementation of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, post model, create table (with indexes) and slow query.

Comment: Do you have any kind of DateTimeField (e.g. creation timestamp or something like this) on your model that you can use to get only the latest entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create another table in the database, and move messages there. For example:

Run `CREATE TABLE emails_archive LIKE emails;` in MySQL.

Then put into the daily cron this job:

```
INSERT INTO emails_archive (SELECT * FROM emails WHERE sent_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), 1 MONTH));
DELETE FROM emails WHERE sent_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), 1 MONTH));
```

That is it!

Comment: I thought of django app for this functionality. But thanks anyway.

Comment: danihp, index is simplier, but when it does not fit into the memory there will be huge problems.